# MS Access VBA and report issue with unicode UTF-8 / UTF-16

Tags: vba, ms-access, unicode, report

I have an issue with MS Access reports. I have a code in VBA where string type sentences are added with some specific local letters (e.g. ąčęėįšų). These are printed to report. However, report changes these letters to unknown and not understandable symbols. This started to happen after changing laptop and seems that unicode has changed from UTF-8 to UTF-16. Is there a simple solution how to solve it in report?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a font?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution myself. If you want to add some symbol, use VBA function "ChrW(xxx)" where instead "xxx" add code for symbol. This solved the case.